# How to access related models in defining a custom attribute

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to define a custom attribute in my sails model and I want to access a certain field in a related table how do I do this in sails? Please check my sample code below

Example:

```
// models/User.js
attributes: {
   name: 'string',
   ...
   // now define the realtionship
   school: { model: 'School' },
  // define custom attribute
  studyIn: function(){
    // returns nothing
    return this.school.name ;
  }
}

// models/School.js
attributes: {
  name: 'string',
  address: 'string',
  students: { collection: 'User', via: 'school' }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: When you find the `User` instance, are you doing `.populate('studyIn')`?

Comment: Apologies, I mean `populate('school')`.

Comment: No I forgot to add populate. Thanks Scott